# How to increase Google Forms content width?

Tags: google-forms

I have a google form for which I have some grid questions, using long labels. This implies that some of the questions are shown with scroll bars I do not want.

is there a way to configure my form to avoid that ?

Comment: I wish this were possible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid (as mentioned by @sandwich as well) there is no way to manipulate the width of the form.
Fortunately **there is a work-around**.

What you could do would be something similar to the example in the images below.

EDITING THE FORM:

[image: editing the grid]

VIEWING THE FORM:

[image]

> What you actually do, is to **dedicate a new section to the question
>   in question, write on the section's description your long labels** and
>   explain how to answer the question.

As you can see on the attached image there are no scroll bars whatsoever.